# why pdo exception happening? and it shows database driver not found

Tags: mysql, yii2

I'm using yii2 framework, while I'm running it locally it shows an error driver not found. how can i fix it??

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
could not find driver
↵
Caused by: PDOException
could not find driver
in G:\xampp\htdocs\edumetrix\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php at line 687
```

Comment: whats in your database config component? add in your question

Answer (score 0):

.Are you using MySQL or another one?

You need install `php-mysql` or `php-pdo`